# Show button title only when user isn't subscribed yet

Tags: ios, swift

I have a user model:

```
struct User {
  let hasBeenSubscribed: Bool
  let title: String
}
```

Then I have a view with button in it where my model is getting listened to (i.e. view gets updated according to model each time).

What I want is:

1. I want to show title "Subscribe" on my button when someone just entered screen with specific user and hasn't subscribed to them yet.
2. If it's the first time seeing specific user screen and if button with "Subscribe" title has been pressed I want to show "Unsubscribe" text on top of it.
3. If it's second or further time I've entered the screen and am already subscribed, I don't want to show the button anymore.
4. If I'm already subscribed to the User, I don't want to show the button.

I've tried to use UserDefaults for that (imagine **creator** is one of the elements of array **[User]** that gets retrieved from backend):

```
let storage = UserDefaults.standard
storage.setValue(creator.hasBeenSubscribed, forKey: creator.title)
if let isAlreadySubscribed = storage.value(forKey: creator.title) as? Bool, isAlreadySubscribed {
  button.isHidden = true
} else {
  button.setTitle("Subscribe", for: [])
  if button.isHighlighted {
    button.setTitle("Unsubscribe", for: [])
    button.isEnabled = false
  }
}
```

I get expected behaviour for scenarios 1, 3 and 4. But for 2, when I press button it gets hidden immediately. How would I go around this problem?

Comment: Saving the value and reading it back immediately is pointless. You do know the value . By the way don't use `value(forKey:`, there is `bool(forKey:` which returns a non-optional

Answer (score 0):

After dividing the time when you are subscribed and not subscribed, the event that occurs when you click the button when you are not subscribed is implemented through 'addTarget'.

```swift
        storage.setValue(creator.hasBeenSubscribed, forKey: creator.title)
        
        if let isAlreadySubscribed = storage.value(forKey: creator.title) as? Bool {
            if isAlreadySubscribed {
                button.isHidden = true // 3,4
                
            } else {
                
                button.setTitle("Subscribe", for: .normal) // 1
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) // 2
            }
        }
    
    @objc func clickButton(_ button: UIButton) {
        button.setTitle("Unsubscribe", for: .normal)
        button.isEnabled = false
    }
```